# Virtually Indexed Caches

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have been having a problem answering the following question:

Explain the challenges if the number of bits in the page offset does not equal the number of bits in the sum of “Index” and “Byte”

Comment: What kind of problem are you having?  I assume "Byte" mean the offset within the cache line, i.e. the low few bits of the address?  So they're asking about the complications when some of the index bits are part of the page number, and aren't translated for free so a VIPT cache doesn't behave like a PIPT cache.  [Virtually addressed Cache](//stackoverflow.com/a/39501028).

Comment: [Virtually indexed physically tagged cache Synonym](//stackoverflow.com/a/46595331)

Comment: [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20789579/4230618).