# How to increase throughput of random memory reads/writes on multi-GB buffers?

Tags: c, memory, cpu-architecture, intel

I keep coming up against this issue, so I would be grateful for shared insights from the resident experts. I can't be the only one who keeps encountering this.

I know I'm using old hardware, but I'm interested in the relevant issues for this sort of hardware and newer. I'm using a 3.2 GHz Ivy Bridge Xeon with 32 GB ECC RAM. It has only 8MB L3 Cache, but since I'm performing random reads and writes on multi-gigabyte buffers, I don't think the L3 cache size is very relevant to this question.

I've found it takes ~100 to read and update a 64 bit integer in a random position in a large buffer of the same. The buffer is aligned so it should only need to load one cache lane for each update. In a single threaded application, that means I get around 10-15 million updates per second. Supposing I had millions of independent such updates to perform, is there a faster way of getting that work done than processing them in sequence? I know I could multi-thread the application, but with only a few hundred cycles latency, does that mean it wouldn't be worth having more threads than cpu cores? I'm looking more for 10X+ speedup not just 2-4X. I have an OpenCL program which does this on an old Tesla GPU with GDDR5 RAM and I can get well over a billion updates per second, but efficient GPU programming is difficult and not friendly to branching code.

My Ivy Bridge CPU doesn't support AVX Gather/Scatter instructions. Would these instructions issue requests for all elements before necessarily receiving any of the responses from memory, or do they serialise the memory requests? The reported cycles per instruction are meaningless in this context because they would be mostly requesting data not in cache already. If they can be used to hide the latency and get multiple elements at once though, that could be really useful.

I don't think there is, but am I missing a trick here? Is there some way in c to use non-blocking memory reads/writes? Many Thanks.

Comment: I found this document https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1761952 which appears to suggest there's no performance to be gained from gather/scatter on a larger buffer, though it also appears to relate to Broadwell architecture only.

Comment: You say you have "random" accesses to perform, and then you also suggest that processing them "in sequence" is among your options.  Those seem contradictory to me.  Would you please clarify?

Comment: *Is there some way in c to use non-blocking memory reads/writes?* No, there isn't, C doesn't have any language features for that. (You might find a library with a C API though.)

Comment: Make sure you're using hugepages, preferably 1G hugepages but at least 2M largepages should reduce TLB misses.  See https://7-cpu.com/cpu/IvyBridge.html for TLB capacity for 2M vs. 4K pages - actually, that seems to be saying that 2M largepage TLB entries don't get cached by the second-level TLB, and there are fewer L1dTLB entries that can cache them.  (Or a separate L1dTLB.)  But still probably more coverage.

Comment: BTW, normal loads and stores are already non-blocking for out-of-order exec CPUs like Ivy Bridge: one of the main purposes of OoO exec is to hide memory latency, especially of cache misses.  It's normal for high-performance CPUs to be capable of hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss.  Ivy Bridge has I think 10 LFB (Line Fill Buffers) which track cache lines in flight to/from L1.  ([How do the store buffer and Line Fill Buffer interact with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61129773) : Skylake has 12).  If you had multiple misses to the same line, load buffers could share LFBs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Okay, maybe 'in sequence' was a bad choice of words, but I was looking at SIMD, though that doesn't appear to be much use for my case. It's currently a single threaded scalar application performing lots of random reads+writes on a multi-gigabyte memory buffer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your suggestion. I hadn't even thought of that. I'm no sysadmin, so I've some work to do to figure out what to do to safely enable and test 1GB hugepages. I've been trying software prefetching on an old AMD laptop that has 3Dnowprefetch, but the results are disappointing. For my case, it doesn't live up to its promise which is a shame because I think its just what I need.

Comment: Why would SW prefetch help?  Do you have only a few random accesses to do between periods of different activity, and the addresses are known well ahead of time?

Comment: @PeterCordes I have lots of addresses known ahead of time. I could prefetch say three of them, then update the fourth of four. By the time that has updated, the other three should be in cache and can update quickly cutting down the average latency by up to three quarters, no? However far ahead the OoO goes, it isn't infinite so will end up with the same latency that it would have without it which is why I'm seeing hundreds of cycles, or is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm using a program I'd previously written to test prefetchting performance. At the moment, it does the above but with just two elements at a time, prefetch1, update2, update1 in a loop. On a 1.6GB array, on my Ivy Bridge Xeon, gccs __builtin_prefetch builds using prefetcht0 instruction, and the time taken to update 100,000,000 hash table entries randomly goes from 8.7 seconds without prefetch to 6.7 with it, plus 10s reading 100,000,000 integers from a file, once it's cached in memory, so actually quite useful, though not half. There was negligible difference on my AMD laptop.

Comment: Oh, if there's significant work involved in each update then yes there's some room for prefetch to help.  Not something like a simple histogram with only a few instructions to load an int and use it as an index.  Note that Ivy Bridge in some cases has some kind of performance pothole with SW prefetch instructions, like one per 43 cycles, vs. 0.5 cycle cost on the previous and next models for data that's already hot in L1d according to Agner Fog's testing (https://agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf). So it can be the opposite of helpful in some cases, but ok in yours.