# Dot-product groups of 4 bytes against 4 small constants, over an array of bytes (efficiently using SIMD)?

Tags: c#, c, assembly, masm, simd

I have a peculiar requirement that needs to be fulfilled efficiently. (SIMD, perhaps?)

`src` is an array of bytes. Every group of 4 bytes in the array need to be processed as:

- Multiply low nibble of `src[0]` by a constant number `A`.
- Multiply low nibble of `src[1]` by a constant number `B`.
- Multiply low nibble of `src[2]` by a constant number `C`.
- Multiply low nibble of `src[3]` by a constant number `D`.

Sum the four parts above to give `result`.

Move on to next 4 set of bytes and re-compute `result` (rinse & repeat till end of byte array).

`result` is guaranteed to be small (even fit in a byte) owing to all numbers involved being very small. However, the data type for `result` can be flexible to support an effecient algorithm.

Any suggestions / tips / tricks to go faster than the following pseudo-code?:

```
for (int i=0; i< length; i+=4)
{
  result = (src[i] & 0x0f) * A + (src[i+1] & 0x0f) * B + (src[i+2] & 0x0f) * C + (src[i+3] & 0x0f) * D;
}
```

BTW, `result` then forms an index into a higher-order array.

This particular loop is so crucial that implementation language is no barrier. Can choose language out of C#, C or MASM64

Comment: "Don't care what language" is not helpful at all. We need to know what language you're *actually* using.

Comment: Can you define what performance requirements you have, and how this approach you've shown here falls short? I'd expect this to be IO bound more than CPU bound. There are SIMD bit-shuffling methods, but I think they're overkill in this particular situation. What you might need to do is restructure your input to be closer to the optimal structure for processing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8193601/1462295

Comment: What aarchitecture are you programming for?  This is just a dot product, for which instructions often exist.

Comment: With a decent compiler you can just express this as is and it would auto-vectorize https://godbolt.org/z/hcTTTW9je

Comment: @fuz: MASM64 implies they're targeting x86-64, and are also willing to use C or C# to generate x86-64 machine code.

Comment: On x86-64 with SSSE3, looks like a job for `pmaddubsw`.  Masking away the high nibble makes a value that works as either signed non-negative or as unsigned, so you can use it as either operand to `_mm256_maddubs_epi16`.  Pick depending on whether A, B, C, D are signed or unsigned.  hsums within groups of 4 results (in 4 bytes) needs one more shuffle and add since `pmaddubsw` already adds horizontally.   `psadbw` against `_mm256_setzero_si256()` does byte hsums within groups of 8 bytes, not 4 so isn't convenient here.

Comment: Presumably you want the `result`s packed for an index vector for `vpgatherdd` aka `_mm256_i32gather_epi32`. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpgatherdd:vpgatherqd  But note that it's slow on some Intel CPUs with microcode workarounds for security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am aware of that.  I am asking anyway because “any language” is suspicious and I'm not going to invest time into writing an answer without OP clarifying his constraints.

Comment: @fuz: My reading of the question is they want to know what asm instructions are useful, and any language with intrinsics or whatever is a usable answer, since they can potentially port it to C or C# intrinsics or whatever they're using.  (But yes, agreed it would be better if they put it more explicitly if that's what they meant.)

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: That's pretty nasty asm.  The OP said the results are known to be small because of known small inputs, but your code with `int result` and `int A,B,C,D` is getting clang to do 32-bit multiplies, having to unpack for a slow `vpmulld`.  https://godbolt.org/z/v9W6G6qhM is somewhat less bad, using `signed char A,B,C,D` and signed or unsigned `short result` lets it use `vpmullw` (16-bit non-widening multiply).  Still much worse than `vpmaddubsw` which takes 8-bit input and adds horizontal pairs of 16-bit products.

Comment: So probably intrinsics are the way to go, especially if we care about optimizers less good than Clang/LLVM where we'll probably have an even harder time hand-holding the compiler into using `vpmaddubsw`.

Comment: The loop makes no sense. Should it be result += ...?

Comment: Here’s the answer I can’t post because stackoverflow community voted to close the question, despite it’s perfectly clear what was asked. https://gist.github.com/Const-me/dfee9f414982262df5e959713f5f63ac

Comment: @Soonts I just reopen voted

Comment: You have tagged multiple language, please choose **one** language.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel SIMD code is language agnostic. You can write them in assembly, C, C++, modern C#, Rust, and quite a few other languages. They directly expose CPU instructions to programmers and therefore easily translatable between languages. Instead of one language tag, SIMD-related questions like that ideally need one tag with the target instruction set. When I wrote my answer, I assumed the instruction set is SSE. While it’s trivial to translate to AVX2, it’s hard to translate to e.g. ARM NEON, the code would be completely different.

Comment: @Soonts That doesn't matter, asking for solutions in C#, C or MASM64 makes this unfocused, which is why it's closed.

Comment: I agree that a SIMD question may be focused even if it asks for solutions in any of several languages. Though I think it is better not to tag such questions like [tag:c#] or [c], and use the freed tag slots to tag instruction sets and domain, like [tag:avx] [tag:x86] [tag:dot-product].

Comment: @SimonGoater: The OP mentions that each `result` will be used as an array index.  So there's more code inside the loop they've omitted, without even a `...` placeholder.  Summing across `result` values would be easier than keeping them separate, then we could use `vpsadbw` to sum groups of 8 bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes In that case, it's highly likely the bottleneck is elsewhere. The OP should include the code in the loop they want to accelerate. If result is to be used as an index in a large array with lots of cache misses, then they could try the technique I used with prefetching. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78132330/how-to-increase-throughput-of-random-memory-reads-writes-on-multi-gb-buffers

Comment: @SimonGoater: Agreed, the optimal strategy might depend on whether the result should be in vectors of `int` elements, or if they're needed as scalar or what.  Although for x86 with SSSE3 probably not, always start with `[v]pand` / `[v]pmaddubsw`, then `[v]pmaddwd` to sum to 32-bit integers unless the surrounding code heavily bottlenecks on the SIMD-multiply execution ports, then you could spend more front-end throughput to do something else.  And yeah, if the array doesn't hit in at least L2 cache, that'll be more of a bottleneck than the dot product, even without vectorizing the dot product.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unless the loop code can also be efficiently vectorised, it probably isn't worth vectorising the calculation of the variable result as you'd immediately have to unvectorize it to use the results. There are only 12 simple operations to calculate result. The overhead of vectorizing/unvectorizing would, I suspect, be too great to make any sense here. You could make a buffer of results I suppose to avoid much of that overhead, but I still think this is probably the wrong place to look for optimisations.

Comment: @SimonGoater: vector store / scalar reload is very efficient.  You can do one or two vectors of dot products, store the results to `int results [8 or 16]`, then loop over that.  The first one will have some store-forwarding latency depending on how far ahead out-of-order exec can get, the rest will probably all be ready.  Fewer total uops is a win for throughput.  Or software-pipeline, like write `results[0..7]` then read `results[8..15]` from the previous outer iteration (or unrolled), so vector ALU + store-forward latency is fully hidden without making OoO exec work hard.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an example how to do that efficiently with SSE intrinsics.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>  // SSE 2
#include <tmmintrin.h>  // SSSE 3
#include <smmintrin.h>  // SSE 4.1

// Vector constants for dot4Sse function
struct ConstantVectorsSse
{
    __m128i abcd;
    __m128i lowNibbleMask;
    __m128i zero;
};

// Pack 4 bytes into a single uint32_t value
uint32_t packBytes( uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t d )
{
    b <<= 8;
    c <<= 16;
    d <<= 24;
    return a | b | c | d;
}

// Initialize vector constants for dot4Sse function
struct ConstantVectorsSse makeConstantsSse( uint8_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t c, uint8_t d )
{
    struct ConstantVectorsSse cv;
    cv.abcd = _mm_set1_epi32( (int)packBytes( a, b, c, d ) );
    cv.lowNibbleMask = _mm_set1_epi8( 0x0F );
    cv.zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
    return cv;
}

// Dot products of 4 groups of 4 bytes in memory against 4 small constants
// Returns a vector of 4 int32 lanes
__m128i dot4Sse( const uint8_t* rsi, const struct ConstantVectorsSse* cv )
{
    // Load 16 bytes, and mask away higher 4 bits in each byte
    __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128( ( const __m128i* )rsi );
    v = _mm_and_si128( cv->lowNibbleMask, v );

    // Compute products, add pairwise
    v = _mm_maddubs_epi16( cv->abcd, v );

    // Final reduction step, add adjacent pairs of uint16_t lanes
    __m128i high = _mm_srli_epi32( v, 16 );
    __m128i low = _mm_blend_epi16( v, cv->zero, 0b10101010 );
    return _mm_add_epi32( high, low );
}
```

The code uses `pmaddubsw` SSSE3 instruction for multiplication and the first step of the reduction, then adds even/odd `uint16_t` lanes in the vector.

The above code assumes your ABCD numbers are unsigned bytes. If they are signed, you gonna need to flip order of arguments of `_mm_maddubs_epi16` intrinsic and use different code for the second reduction step, `_mm_slli_epi32( v, 16 )`, `_mm_add_epi16`, `_mm_srai_epi32( v, 16 )`

If you have AVX2 the upgrade is trivial, replace `__m128i` with `__m256i`, and  `_mm_something` with `_mm256_something`.

If the length of your input is not necessarily a multiple of 4 groups, note you gonna need special handling for the final incomplete batch of numbers. Without `_mm_maskload_epi32` AVX2 instruction, here's one possible way to load incomplete vector of 4-byte groups:

```c
__m128i loadPartial( const uint8_t* rsi, size_t rem )
{
    assert( rem != 0 && rem < 4 );
    __m128i v;
    switch( rem )
    {
    case 1:
        v = _mm_cvtsi32_si128( *(const int*)( rsi ) );
        break;
    case 2:
        v = _mm_cvtsi64_si128( *(const int64_t*)( rsi ) );
        break;
    case 3:
        v = _mm_cvtsi64_si128( *(const int64_t*)( rsi ) );
        v = _mm_insert_epi32( v, *(const int*)( rsi + 8 ), 2 );
        break;
    }
    return v;
}
```

P.S. Since you then gonna use these integers to index, note it only takes a few cycles of latency to extract integers from SSE vectors with `_mm_extract_epi32` instruction.

Comment: The final 3 instructions could be `pmaddwd` against a vector of `set1_epi16(1)` which would sign-extend the 16-bit pairs and add them.  That's two multiplies per iteration, but the OP is talking about using `result` for array indexing so probably the surrounding code isn't also bottlenecked on those ports.