# Phy memory set + offset bigger than page offset

Tags: memory-management, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

I understood that their is a way that even when cache set + offset bigger than page offset, the cache don't need to wait for finding the physical page number and using 2-3 lsb of the virtual page number as msb of the set, in this way it just took 2 clocks instead of 3 to reach the data. What is the name of it? Any relevant links are welcome

Comment: Are you talking about way prediction?  Or ISAs where possible aliasing is software-visible unless the OS does page-coloring like in [Virtually indexed physically tagged cache Synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46588219)

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, I meant VIPT, just didn't know that name