# Assembly - Can I declare variables inside a Procedure?

Tags: assembly

Well the question is straightforward.
I want to know if declaring variables inside procedures is a okay thing to do.
like this for example:

```
SAMPLE PROC NEAR
    ; PROC BODY
RET
VARIABLE DW 0000H
SAMPLE ENDP
```

I don't think this should be an error. As RET is available at the end.
What I want really to do is have an array of constants that is required for the PROC. Some sort of look up table.

If it is not legal, I would like to know why.

Comment: Mixing data with code is a disadvantage on most architectures, including x86.  Having the same line in L1I cache and L1D cache at the same time is a waste.  (All modern CPUs have split L1 caches, [for several reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38549736/224132))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procedure boundaries are almost meaningless in assembly. It doesn't matter if the variable is before or after ENDP. So yeah, syntax-wise it's OK, as long as you're not trying to execute the variable contents as code. But there's a deeper issue here.

Protected mode systems (Windows, Linux) often make the code section read only; trying to write into such a variable would crash the program. You have to use the data section or the stack.

Under DOS, it's okay.

Comment: Even when possible, keeping read/data next to code (in the same cache line) is still a performance disaster: the CPU will flush the pipeline after every store to a cache line that also contains code that's fetched or executing.  Or even within the aligned 1k region on older CPUs.  (`machine_clears.smc` performance event): [Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395557).  The OP's proposed read-only lookup table doesn't have this problem, merely [a waste of L1i/d and i/dTLB footprint.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609077/224132)