# why do we need to keep cache size small?

Tags: caching, tlb

I am understanding the concept of TLB (MMU). i am confusing if caches (like the TLB) are so great, why don’t we just make bigger caches and keep all of our data in them.

Comment: Bit broad, but still an interesting question...

Answer (score 1):

Simple: such caches are **expensive**. The reason why they are so *helpful* is: they are carefully "fine tuned". They are located "very close" to where they are required.

You might want to read about [memory hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy) to understand the balancing between **cost** and "speed" requirements.

Comment: Also, making caches bigger would slow them down, if you increased the size by a lot.  [Why is the size of L1 cache smaller than that of the L2 cache in most of the processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549736) Even with an unlimited power budget, speed-of-light and gate delays in decoding complexity would probably stop you from building a 4GiB L1d cache that's as fast as a real-world 32k or 48k cache out of multi-ported SRAM.  Although a huge L3 or L4 cache is at least plausible, just not worth it.  (Except off-chip with eDRAM or HBM.)