# Why does level 1 use split cache?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, second-level-cache, first-level-cache

Generally, what processors follow is that level 1 cache is split while level 2 in unified cache. Why is it so? 
I'm not aware of any processor designed in the last 15 years that has a unified (L1) cache.

Comment: One cache with the total number of read / write ports would be slower and higher power. 
 And wouldn't have the physical proximity advantages of being near load/store ports vs. near front-end fetch stage.

Comment: Also related: [Why is the size of L1 cache smaller than that of the L2 cache in most of the processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4666728) re: why we have multi-level caches, with some more details about CPU caches.  My answer there also describes why we make split L1 caches.