# software threads vs hardware threads

Tags: multithreading, hardware

What is the difference between software threads, hardware threads and java threads?

Are software threads, java threads and hardware threads independent or interdependent?
I am asking this because, I know Java threads are created inside a process with in jvm (java.exe).

Also is it true that these different process are executed on different hardware threads?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Software threads are threads of execution managed by the operating system.

Hardware threads are a feature of some processors that allow better utilisation of the processor under some circumstances.  They may be exposed to/by the operating system as appearing to be additional cores ("hyperthreading").

In Java, the threads you create maintain the software thread abstraction, where the JVM is the "operating system".  Whether the JVM then maps Java threads to OS threads is the JVM's business (but it almost certainly does).  And then the OS will be using hardware threads if they are available.

Answer (score 116):

A "hardware thread" is a physical CPU or core. So, a 4 core CPU can ***genuinely*** support 4 hardware threads at once - the CPU really is doing 4 things at the same time.

One hardware thread can run many software threads. In modern operating systems, this is often done by time-slicing - each thread gets a few milliseconds to execute before the OS schedules another thread to run on that CPU. Since the OS switches back and forth between the threads quickly, it ***appears*** as if one CPU is doing more than one thing at once, but in reality, a core is still running only one hardware thread, which switches between many software threads.

Modern JVMs map java threads directly to the native threads provided by the OS, so there is no inherent overhead introduced by java threads vs native threads. As to hardware threads, the OS tries to map threads to cores, if there are sufficient cores. So, if you have a java program that starts 4 threads, and have 4 or more cores, there's a good chance your 4 threads will run truly in parallel on 4 separate cores, if the cores are idle.

Comment: *most* new expensive chips have multiple hardware threads per core.  Hyperthreading and so on have been around a fair few years now and are pervasive.

Comment: sure, I'm trying to keep the discussion simple, and not get into details about the specific cpu architecture, since this was a java question. Whether the hardware threading be implemented per processor (as it was not so long ago), per core or per hyperthread, or some other architectural mechanism to provide hardware parallelism, the primary distinction between software and hardware threads is the same.

Comment: Sorry but can someone please explain what "native threads" mean in the context of this answer? Are they referring to hardware threads or software threads or both?

Comment: A native thread is exposed by the OS. As opposed to [green threads](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) which are just simulated by a user program.

Comment: Is there any relation between hardware/software threads and Kernel/User level threads? Are they the same?

Answer (score 9):

**Hardware threads (e.g. Intel Hyperthreading) are a cheaper and slower alternative to having multiple-cores**

Software threads are a software abstraction implemented by the (Linux) kernel:

- either the kernel runs one software thread per CPU (or hyperthread)
- or it fakes it with the scheduler by running a process for a bit, then a timer interrupt comes, then it switches to another process, and so on

Key to their implementation is the hardware provided and kernel configured separation between userland and kerneland: [What are Ring 0 and Ring 3 in the context of operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717016/what-are-ring-0-and-ring-3-in-the-context-of-operating-systems/44483439#44483439)

I will now focus on hardware threads, which is the more obscure hardware question, with a focus on Intel's implementation which it calls Hyperthreading.

The [Intel Manual Volume 3 System Programming Guide - 325384-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081259/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) 8.7 "INTEL HYPER-THREADING TECHNOLOGY ARCHITECTURE" describes HT briefly. It contains the following diagram:

[image]

TODO it is slower by how much percent in average in real applications?

Hyperthreading is possible because modern single CPUs cores already execute multiple instructions at once with the instruction pipeline https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining

The instruction pipeline is a separation of functions inside of a single core to ensure that each part of the circuit is used at any given time: reading memory, decoding instructions, executing instructions, etc.

Hyperthreading separates functions further by using:

- a single backend, which actually runs the instructions with its pipeline.

  Dual core has two backends, which explains the greater cost and performance.
- two front-ends, which take two streams of instructions and order them in a way to maximize pipelining usage of the single backend by avoiding [hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29).

  Dual core would also have 2 front-ends, one for each backend.

  There are edge cases where instruction reordering produces no benefit, making hyperthreading useless. But it produces a significant improvement in average.

Two hyperthreads in a single core share further cache levels (TODO how many? L1?) than two different cores, which share only L3, see:

- [Multiple threads and CPU cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802565/multiple-threads-and-cpu-cache/54018751#54018751)
- [How are cache memories shared in multicore Intel CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944966/how-are-cache-memories-shared-in-multicore-intel-cpus/33510874#33510874)

The interface that each hyperthread exposes to the operating system is similar to that of an actual core, and both can be controlled separately. Thus `cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows me 4 processors, even though I only have 2 cores with 2 hyperthreads each.

Operating systems can however take advantage of knowing which hyperthreads are on the same core to run multiple threads of a given program on a single core, which might improve cache usage.

This LinusTechTips video contains a light-hearted non-technical explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnS50lJicXc

Comment: A really good short answer to how a single CPU core can provide multiple threads. It adds up to the accepted answer to give a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Hardware threads can be thought of as the CPU cores, although each core can run multiple threads. Most of the CPUs mention how many threads can be run on each core (on linux, lscpu command gives this detail). These are the number of cores that can be used in parallel.

Software threads are abstraction to the hardware to make multi-processing possible. If you have multiple software threads but there are not multiple resources then these software threads are a way to run all tasks in parallel by allocating resources for limited time(or using some other strategy) so that it appears that all threads are running in parallel. These are managed by the operating system. Java thread is an abstraction at the JVM level.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are mistaken. I never heard about hardware threads (unless you mean hyper threading on certain intel machines). Every process is a running representation of a program. Threads are simultaneous execution flows with in a process. Java thread definitions are mapped to system threads by JVM. Java used to have a concept of [GreenThreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads), which is  no longer the case.

Comment: Inmos transputers supported any number of threads, the chip was the scheduler, no OS involved.

Comment: stackover flow ask me to add comment ;)

Comment: Your contributions regarding java threads is helpful. Your comments about hardware threads seem inaccurate though. Software is able to ask for more threads than are "available" (these are software threads). "Available" refers to whatever the CPU provides as a feature, e.g. hyperthreaded 4-core machine, 8 threads (these are the hardware threads). Typically don't want to surpass the number of hardware threads all too much. Basically, you need some CPU core to run the thread at the end of the day. The software thread is intimately linked to the hardware thread