# explanation regarding multi-core processor vs multiple processors with single core

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

I know OS schedules thread and CPU executes it and there is direct relationship between no of threads and no of cores.Is that mean single processor with multiple cores (say n) is same as that of n single core processors, I mean In both of these cases processing ability is same or there is some difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**yes**, there is a difference, but for normal programming decisions the difference is almost **insignificant** and too low-level.

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) contains some explanation in chapters "Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology" and "Multi-Core Technology"

Similar questions:

- [SuperUser: Hyper-Threading and Dual-Core, What's the Difference?](https://superuser.com/questions/133082/hyper-threading-and-dual-core-whats-the-difference)
- [Stack Overflow: multi-CPU, multi-core and hyper-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680684/multi-cpu-multi-core-and-hyper-thread).

What typical programmers might care about when solving parallel programming problems/questions:

- [Intel® Developer Zone: Performance](https://software.intel.com/en-us/performance)
- [Intel Guide for Developing Multithreaded Applications](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-guide-for-developing-multithreaded-applications)

Related articles:

- [Wikipedia: Multi-core processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor)
- [Wikipedia: Hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)