# Is an extra move somehow faster when doing division-by-multiplication?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, clang, x86-64

Consider this function:

```
unsigned long f(unsigned long x) {
    return x / 7;
}
```

With `-O3`, Clang [turns the division into a multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935/7509065), as expected:

```
f:                                      # @f
        movabs  rcx, 2635249153387078803
        mov     rax, rdi
        mul     rcx
        sub     rdi, rdx
        shr     rdi
        lea     rax, [rdi + rdx]
        shr     rax, 2
        ret
```

GCC does basically the same thing, except for using `rdx` where Clang uses `rcx`. But they both appear to be doing an extra move. Why not this instead?

```
f:
        movabs  rax, 2635249153387078803
        mul     rdi
        sub     rdi, rdx
        shr     rdi
        lea     rax, [rdi + rdx]
        shr     rax, 2
        ret
```

In particular, they both put the numerator in `rax`, but by putting the magic number there instead, you avoid having to move the numerator at all. If this is actually better, I'm surprised that neither GCC nor Clang do it this way, since it feels so obvious. Is there some microarchitectural reason that their way is actually faster than my way?

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/UpbDtG).

Comment: If you set `-march=broadwell` or `-march=atom` you can also see some differences. It must be some architectural reason. (there are multiple ALUs and other units so it could be faster even if more instruction used, maybe the first version allow better scheduling or something)

Comment: @Eraklon: Actual in-order Atom (pre-Silvermont) runs `lea` on the AGUs earlier in the pipeline than other instructions like `mov`; GCC often prefers LEA there.  (And will hopefully try to avoid 64-bit multiply for 32-bit operands, unlike on big-core CPUs where `imul r64,r64` is faster than `mul r32`).  I'm not sure why GCC thinks it's a good idea to avoid `lea  rax, [rdx+rdi]` on BDW but that doesn't look like a good idea or a win in this case.  **The code in the question very much looks like a missed optimization by both gcc and clang; no benefit to that extra `mov`.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very much looks like a missed optimization by both gcc and clang; no benefit to that extra mov.

If it's not already reported, GCC and LLVM both accept missed-optimization bug reports: https://bugs.llvm.org/ and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.  For GCC there's even a bug tag "missed-optimization".

---

Wasted `mov` instructions are unfortunately not rare, especially when looking at tiny functions where the input / output regs are nailed down the calling convention, not up to the register allocator.  The do still happen in loops sometimes, like doing a bunch of extra work each iteration so everything is in the right places for the code that runs once after a loop.  /facepalm.

Zero-latency `mov` (mov-elimination) helps reduce the cost of such missed optimizations (and cases where `mov` isn't avoidable), but it still takes a front-end uop so it's pretty much strictly worse.  (Except by chance where it helps alignment of something later, but if that's the reason then a `nop` would have been as good).

And it takes up space in the ROB, reducing how far ahead out-of-order exec can see past a cache miss or other stall.  `mov` is never truly free, only the execution-unit and latency part is eliminated - [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342)

---

My total guess about compiler internals:

Probably gcc/clang's internal machinery need to learn that this division pattern is commutative and can take the input value in some other register and put the constant in RAX.

In a loop they'd want the constant in some other register so they could reuse it, but hopefully the compiler could still figure that out for cases where it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 generates the code you expected, rcx = input dividend:

```
        mov     rax, 2635249153387078803
        mul     rcx
        sub     rcx, rdx
        shr     rcx, 1
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx]
        shr     rax, 2
```

---

A divisor of 7 needs a 65 bit multiplier to get the proper accuracy.

```
floor((2^(64+ceil(log2(7))))/7)+1 = floor((2^67)/7)+1 = 21081993227096630419
```

Removing the most significant bit, 2^64, results in 21081993227096630419 - 2^64 = 2635249153387078803, which is the multiplier actually used in the code.

The generated code compensates for the missing 2^64 bit, which is explained in figure 4.1 and equation 4.5 in this pdf file:

https://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf

Further explanation can be seen in this prior answer:

[Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/41224096#41224096)

If the 65 bit multiplier has a trailing 0 bit, then it can be shifted right 1 bit to result in a 64 bit multiplier, reducing the number of instructions. For example if dividing by 5:

```
floor((2^(64+ceil(log2(5))))/5)+1 = floor((2^67)/5)+1 = 29514790517935282586
29514790517935282586 >> 1 = 14757395258967641293

        mov     rax, -3689348814741910323 ; == 14757395258967641293 ==  0cccccccccccccccdH
        mul     rcx
        shr     rdx, 2
        mov     rax, rdx
```

Answer (score -1):

Your version does *not* appear to be faster.

**Edit:**  The ROB (reorder buffer) can do register renaming, so the extra `mov` does *not* actually have to move any data. It can merely adjust the index into the PRF [physical register file] for the generated uop. So, the `mov` is possibly fused away.

---

I've coded up both your asm versions:

---

Here is `orig.s`:

```
    .file   "orig.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  orig
    .type   orig, @function
orig:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movabsq $2635249153387078803, %rdx
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    mulq    %rdx
    subq    %rdx, %rdi
    shrq    %rdi
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdi), %rax
    shrq    $2, %rax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   orig, .-orig
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

---

And, `fix1.s`:

```
    .file   "fix1.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  fix1
    .type   fix1, @function
fix1:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movabsq $2635249153387078803, %rax
    mulq    %rdi
    subq    %rdx, %rdi
    shrq    %rdi
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdi), %rax
    shrq    $2, %rax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   fix1, .-fix1
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

---

Here is a test program, `main.c`. (You may need to vary the iteration constant in `test`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

ulong orig(ulong);
ulong fix1(ulong);

typedef ulong (*fnc_p)(ulong);

typedef long long tsc_t;

static inline tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

tsc_t
test(fnc_p fnc)
{
    tsc_t beg;
    tsc_t end;
    ulong tot = 0;

    beg = tscget();

    for (ulong cnt = 10000000;  cnt > 0;  --cnt)
        tot += fnc(cnt);

    end = tscget();

    end -= beg;

    return end;
}

int
main(void)
{

    tsc_t odif = test(orig);
    tsc_t fdif = test(fix1);

    printf("odif=%lld fdif=%lld (%lld)\n",odif,fdif,odif - fdif);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Build with:

```
gcc -O3 -o main main.c orig.s fix1.s
```

---

Here are test test results of 20 runs:

```
odif=43937784 fdif=34104334 (9833450)
odif=39791246 fdif=42641752 (-2850506)
odif=25818191 fdif=25586750 (231441)
odif=35056015 fdif=25276729 (9779286)
odif=43955175 fdif=31112246 (12842929)
odif=25731472 fdif=25493826 (237646)
odif=25627395 fdif=26202191 (-574796)
odif=28029957 fdif=25627366 (2402591)
odif=25828608 fdif=26291294 (-462686)
odif=25690703 fdif=25703610 (-12907)
odif=25908418 fdif=26411828 (-503410)
odif=25690776 fdif=25673766 (17010)
odif=25992890 fdif=25982718 (10172)
odif=25693459 fdif=25636974 (56485)
odif=26572724 fdif=25870050 (702674)
odif=25627334 fdif=25621802 (5532)
odif=27760054 fdif=27382748 (377306)
odif=26343245 fdif=26195134 (148111)
odif=27289865 fdif=25840818 (1449047)
odif=25985794 fdif=25721351 (264443)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Your data doesn't appear to support your conclusion, unless I'm misinterpreting something.

Like I said, you may have to vary the number of iterations (up or down). Or, do many runs and take the minimum. But, otherwise, I would expect the final number on each line to be more or less invariant either positive or negative, not swinging +/-. It may be difficult to measure, without a better test

You should note that modern x86 models (e.g. `Sandy Bridge` or later), do *massive* superscalar and instruction reorder, along with fusing uops, so I wouldn't count on a literal translation. For example, see: https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/

Here's a better(?) version, but it still shows the *same* thing. Namely, that sometimes original is faster and sometimes "improved" is faster

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

ulong orig(ulong);
ulong fix1(ulong);

typedef ulong (*fnc_p)(ulong);

typedef long long tsc_t;

typedef struct {
    tsc_t orig;
    tsc_t fix1;
} bnc_t;

#define BNCMAX      100
bnc_t bnclist[BNCMAX];

static inline tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

tsc_t
test(fnc_p fnc)
{
    tsc_t beg;
    tsc_t end;
    ulong tot = 0;

    beg = tscget();

    for (ulong cnt = 10000000;  cnt > 0;  --cnt)
        tot += fnc(cnt);

    end = tscget();

    end -= beg;

    return end;
}

void
run(bnc_t *bnc)
{
    tsc_t odif = test(orig);
    tsc_t fdif = test(fix1);

    bnc->orig = odif;
    bnc->fix1 = fdif;
}

int
main(void)
{
    bnc_t *bnc;

    for (int pass = 0;  pass < BNCMAX;  ++pass) {
        bnc = &bnclist[pass];
        run(bnc);
    }

    for (int pass = 0;  pass < BNCMAX;  ++pass) {
        bnc = &bnclist[pass];
        printf("orig=%lld fix1=%lld (%lld)\n",
            bnc->orig,bnc->fix1,bnc->orig - bnc->fix1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And, here's the output (no real change):

```
orig=31588215 fix1=26821473 (4766742)
orig=25748732 fix1=25917183 (-168451)
orig=25805426 fix1=25635759 (169667)
orig=25479642 fix1=26037620 (-557978)
orig=26668860 fix1=25959444 (709416)
orig=26047616 fix1=25540493 (507123)
orig=25772292 fix1=25460041 (312251)
orig=25709852 fix1=26172701 (-462849)
orig=26124151 fix1=25766472 (357679)
orig=25539018 fix1=26845018 (-1306000)
orig=26884105 fix1=26869566 (14539)
orig=26184938 fix1=27826408 (-1641470)
orig=25841934 fix1=25482603 (359331)
orig=25509107 fix1=25436511 (72596)
orig=25448812 fix1=25473302 (-24490)
orig=25433894 fix1=25812646 (-378752)
orig=25868190 fix1=26180032 (-311842)
orig=25451573 fix1=25503657 (-52084)
orig=25393540 fix1=25484952 (-91412)
orig=26032526 fix1=26825219 (-792693)
orig=25859126 fix1=25529430 (329696)
orig=25692214 fix1=25431668 (260546)
orig=25463849 fix1=25370236 (93613)
orig=25650185 fix1=25401441 (248744)
orig=25702951 fix1=26858126 (-1155175)
orig=26187072 fix1=25800102 (386970)
orig=26493916 fix1=25591639 (902277)
orig=26456983 fix1=25724181 (732802)
orig=25842746 fix1=26119019 (-276273)
orig=26654148 fix1=29452577 (-2798429)
orig=27936505 fix1=28494045 (-557540)
orig=30067162 fix1=27029523 (3037639)
orig=25785637 fix1=25856415 (-70778)
orig=25521760 fix1=25286859 (234901)
orig=25433035 fix1=25626380 (-193345)
orig=25373358 fix1=25541615 (-168257)
orig=25846496 fix1=25446494 (400002)
orig=25368198 fix1=25321934 (46264)
orig=25615453 fix1=28574223 (-2958770)
orig=26660896 fix1=25508745 (1152151)
orig=25891979 fix1=25546436 (345543)
orig=25296369 fix1=25382779 (-86410)
orig=25438794 fix1=25372736 (66058)
orig=25531652 fix1=25498422 (33230)
orig=25977272 fix1=25456931 (520341)
orig=25336327 fix1=25423638 (-87311)
orig=26037148 fix1=25313703 (723445)
orig=25314995 fix1=25538181 (-223186)
orig=26638367 fix1=26446762 (191605)
orig=25915537 fix1=25633327 (282210)
orig=25409105 fix1=25287069 (122036)
orig=25633931 fix1=26423463 (-789532)
orig=26074523 fix1=26524398 (-449875)
orig=25602157 fix1=25580893 (21264)
orig=25490481 fix1=25557287 (-66806)
orig=25666843 fix1=25496179 (170664)
orig=26573635 fix1=25796737 (776898)
orig=26133811 fix1=26226840 (-93029)
orig=28262664 fix1=26022265 (2240399)
orig=25336820 fix1=25683095 (-346275)
orig=25899602 fix1=25660778 (238824)
orig=25440453 fix1=25630320 (-189867)
orig=25356601 fix1=25422670 (-66069)
orig=25419887 fix1=25611533 (-191646)
orig=25766460 fix1=25596927 (169533)
orig=25619510 fix1=25449303 (170207)
orig=25359373 fix1=25380306 (-20933)
orig=25474687 fix1=27194210 (-1719523)
orig=26389253 fix1=26709738 (-320485)
orig=26132999 fix1=25671907 (461092)
orig=25416724 fix1=25540911 (-124187)
orig=25440277 fix1=25364387 (75890)
orig=25704885 fix1=25661456 (43429)
orig=25544376 fix1=25380520 (163856)
orig=25340926 fix1=25956342 (-615416)
orig=25383668 fix1=25397807 (-14139)
orig=25636178 fix1=25769479 (-133301)
orig=26237022 fix1=29897502 (-3660480)
orig=28235814 fix1=25475574 (2760240)
orig=25457466 fix1=25450557 (6909)
orig=25775658 fix1=25802380 (-26722)
orig=27577521 fix1=25444772 (2132749)
orig=25380927 fix1=25409250 (-28323)
orig=25417872 fix1=25336530 (81342)
orig=25995656 fix1=26338512 (-342856)
orig=25553088 fix1=25334495 (218593)
orig=25416197 fix1=25521031 (-104834)
orig=29150160 fix1=25717390 (3432770)
orig=26026892 fix1=26916678 (-889786)
orig=25694048 fix1=25496660 (197388)
orig=25576011 fix1=25676045 (-100034)
orig=25461907 fix1=25462593 (-686)
orig=25736879 fix1=27349093 (-1612214)
orig=25687558 fix1=25829963 (-142405)
orig=25492417 fix1=25752421 (-260004)
orig=25559702 fix1=25423874 (135828)
orig=25799145 fix1=28961932 (-3162787)
orig=25912111 fix1=26018163 (-106052)
orig=25725927 fix1=25794091 (-68164)
orig=25528795 fix1=25855893 (-327098)
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Here's my newest test version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

ulong orig(ulong);
ulong fix1(ulong);

typedef ulong (*fnc_p)(ulong);

typedef long long tsc_t;

typedef struct {
    tsc_t dif;
    ulong tot;
} test_t;

typedef struct {
    test_t orig;
    test_t fix1;
} bnc_t;

#define BNCMAX      100
bnc_t bnclist[BNCMAX];

ulong itermax;

static inline tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

tsc_t
test(test_t *tst,fnc_p fnc)
{
    tsc_t beg;
    tsc_t end;
    ulong tot = 0;

    beg = tscget();

    for (ulong cnt = itermax;  cnt > 0;  --cnt)
        tot += fnc(cnt);

    end = tscget();
    end -= beg;

    tst->dif = end;
    tst->tot = tot;

    return end;
}

void
run(bnc_t *bnc)
{
    tsc_t odif = test(&bnc->orig,orig);
    tsc_t fdif = test(&bnc->fix1,fix1);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    bnc_t *bnc;
    test_t bestorig;
    test_t bestfix1;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc > 0)
        itermax = atoll(*argv);
    else
        itermax = 10000000;

    for (int pass = 0;  pass < BNCMAX;  ++pass) {
        bnc = &bnclist[pass];
        run(bnc);
    }

    bnc = &bnclist[0];
    bestorig = bnc->orig;
    bestfix1 = bnc->orig;

    for (int pass = 0;  pass < BNCMAX;  ++pass) {
        bnc = &bnclist[pass];

        printf("orig=%lld fix1=%lld (%lld)\n",
            bnc->orig.dif,bnc->fix1.dif,bnc->orig.dif - bnc->fix1.dif);
        if (bnc->orig.tot != bnc->fix1.tot)
            printf("FAIL: orig=%ld fix1=%ld\n",bnc->orig.tot,bnc->fix1.tot);

        if (bnc->orig.dif < bestorig.dif)
            bestorig = bnc->orig;

        if (bnc->fix1.dif < bestfix1.dif)
            bestfix1 = bnc->fix1;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("itermax=%ld\n",itermax);
    printf("orig=%lld\n",bestorig.dif);
    printf("fix1=%lld\n",bestfix1.dif);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your data doesn't appear to support your conclusion, unless I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: Like I said, you may have to vary the number of iterations (up or down). Or, do many runs and take the minimum. But, otherwise, I would expect the final number on each line to be more or less invariant either positive or negative, not swinging +/-. It may be difficult to measure, without a better test

Comment: Aside from the problem that your results vary so much they indicate the measurement is insufficiently controlled to obtain good data, measuring a simple execution of the function in a loop is insufficient to tell whether it is more efficient. Two pieces of code may run in identical time when each is executed by itself in a loop, but one may have more resources in use whereas the other has some slack, with the consequence that the first may run slower when executed in some heavy-load context whereas the other performs better. One obvious such resource is instruction cache space.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The I-cache space doesn't factor in because the amount of code is so small. There is not-much D-cache usage to speak of. I have [yet] another version that takes the _best_ run for each version. Still, the results vary as I've described. As I said, iteration count should vary (original produced times of 25ms--too long). New version can specify the count, and at 500000, original is about 100ns faster. And, still varies. Consider the test to a typical workload, so insignificant improvement, and sometime degradation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Why don't you download and run the test yourself. If you wish to critique the test, improve it, or write one yourself. You should be able to come up with a version that consistently proves your case. You [guys] _think_ the fix has to be faster, so you're arguing that way. So, devise such a test.

Comment: *So, the mov is possibly fused away.* - no, [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342) - it's never free.  It doesn't fuse into mov-and-mul uop.  Only the back-end *unfused-domain* (execution units) part is eliminated (in the RS aka scheduler, not ROB).  Also, it still costs code size.

Comment: re: experimental testing: You're only going to be able to measure a downside in a situation where front-end throughput is the bottleneck.  This should be fairly possible in a throughput benchmark if you don't have function boundaries interfering.  (Or a long dep chain such that the extra uop in the ROB maybe limits the ability of OoO exec to see farther and find more ILP).  Call/ret overhead is a big complicating factor; put the work in a loop, not a function.  Most of the time the expected result is going to be break-even, both equal speed.

Comment: Re “You [guys] *think* the fix has to be faster…”: I have neither stated nor formed such a belief. I stated the information in this answer is insufficient to support a conclusion.

Comment: Re “The I-cache space doesn't factor in because the amount of code is so small”: This speaks only to the case in which the code is measured in isolation, or in a context where the instruction cache is not in demand. It does not speak to the situation in which instruction cache is in demand because this code is used with other code that is overflowing cache, or is at least overflow some cache sets.